# ${user.fname} should return the user first name to the user page but its showing as it is its not showing the user first name

Tags: node.js

`${user.fname}` should return the user first name to the user page but its showing as it is its not showing the user first name.

[image]

My code:

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();
const users = [
    {
        fname : "john",
        lname : "yo",enter code here
        age  : 25
    },
    {
        fname : "tharun",
        lname : "bp",
        age : 20
    }
]


/// all routes in here are starting with /users

router.get("/", (req,res) => {
    console.log(users)
    res.send(users);
} );
router.post("/", (req,res) => {
const user = req.body;
users.push(user);
    res.send('USER WITH THE NAME   ${user.fname}  added to the DB');
});
```

In postman in the below section it should show "USER WITH THE NAME jonny added to the DB"

[image: image here]

Comment: Could you add a CURL script instead of a Postman image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the backtick char to apply [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?retiredLocale=it):

```
`
```

```
- res.send('USER WITH THE NAME   ${user.fname}  added to the DB');
+ res.send(`USER WITH THE NAME   ${user.fname}  added to the DB`);
```